# Can't import a method in a file in Python

Tags: python, import

I'm creating a project with the following format.

[image]

In the data_transformation.py following import is made.

```
from src.utills import save_object
```

Main main function is in data_ingestion.py. It calls data_transformation.py and data_transformation.py calls save_object method as mentioned above.

[image]

above is the save_object.
But I'm unable to import this method correctly. Always getting the error below.

[image]

Can someone kindly let me know the issue that I have made here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't know your project's file structure.  It has no idea where to find `src`.  You can do this to add the folder containing "src" to the Python path:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.abspath(os.dirname(__file__)+'../..'))
from src.utils import save_object
```

Comment: But I was able to import, from src.exception import CustomException without any issue in the same file and no error was there. Evenafter sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'../..')), the same error is there

Comment: You were able to import in `utills.py` which is in `src` so `src` is recognized, but in the second case `data_transformation.py` in `src>components` so `src` is not recognized.

Comment: If `src.utills` was recognized then `src.components` would be recognized.